# Smartphone indicator light colors - conventional meaning?

Tags: indicator, smartphone

This is something I noticed on my Android device. When you have a notification, there's a slowly pulsing notification light when your phone is sleeping.

e.g.

[image]

This light comes in different colors, I've seen it as white, blue, and green. This seems to be something that can be controlled by the app that sends the notification. E.g. Facebook is blue, Twitter is green.

Are there conventions as to what the color ought to represent? A quick google search doesn't bring up anything specific.

Comment: why the downvote? this is a very interesting question!

Comment: I found some answers, but they all refer to apps, aren't you using an app to control this?

Comment: Likely downvoted because people follow the "if there is no standard then it's the dev's decision, meaning it was his opinion, i.e. opinion based" I've seen downvote/close votes for that more than once. Also at least for my old android you could change that color for different apps, messenger purple, missed call orange, etc. So it may actually be purely opinion or phone's defaults.

Comment: I found a reference that red indicator is shown if your phone has low battery, which makes sense. The rest of it seems to be about an app that you download to allow the user to adjust the colors. So if there's no conventions and it's truly a stylistic decision, then it's good to know. And @Devin no, there's no way to adjust this on my stock android without downloading a utility app. Somehow I'm getting those default colors.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no standard for this - Google does not even refer to it in the [Material Design guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/notifications.html#notifications-content).

[In the Android Developers Guidelines:](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html)

> Pulse the notification LED appropriately
>
> The user's control over notifications should extend to the LED. When you use DEFAULT_LIGHTS, the LED will glow white. **Your notifications shouldn't use a different color unless the user has explicitly customized it** [emphasis mine].

It will be up to the app and the capabilities of the device as to what colour will be shown, as of early 2016, Android phones do not have a standard pattern for this.

iPhones do not have a comparable notification light - the only thing close to it is the LED flash on the back, which only flashes in one colour.

Comment: I don't think the fact that it is not included in Material Design is a good reason, Material Design is made for on screen UI design not these lights that are in the hardware. If anywhere in their specs it would likely be in their general design docs more specifically the [Android Handheld Devices section](http://developer.android.com/design/handhelds/index.html) where they note things such as the system bar and notifications.

Comment: Great comment, will update answer (although I don't think that link disproves it!)

Comment: In other words, the guidelines say to use the standard "white" for LED. However, app developers customize the color way more than is recommended by the guidelines without explicit user request. Thanks!